# Non-dispersive magnetic medium

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, definition, dispersion

I am aware of how we define a dispersive and a non-dispersive medium. In my script the following is said: "Most media are not magnetically dispersive."

What it is meant with that? What does it mean to have a magnetic non-dispersive medium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dispersion is caused by different propagation speeds at different frequencies.

The speed of propagation of waves in a given media is given as:

$$v = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\mu \epsilon}}$$

In a typical dispersive medium, the speed is given as

$$v(\nu) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\mu \epsilon(\nu)}}$$

where $v$ and $\epsilon$ are functions of frequency while $\mu$ is a NOT a function of frequency. In a "nonmagnetic" medium, $\mu = \mu_0$.

The typical dispersive medium I described would be an example of a a medium that is magnetically non-dispersive. It could still be "electrically" dispersive ($\epsilon = \epsilon(\nu)$).

Comment: the speed you wrote is the phase velocity or the group velocity ?

Comment: It is the velocity at a particular frequency. So it is the phase velocity $at$ that frequency. A group velocity would refer to the velocity of the entire pulse which would typically have many frequencies